# oracle, missing right parenthesis when adding subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

The inner query is as follow, which works fine independently

```
select graduate.univid
from graduate, projectmanager, university
where graduate.empid = projectmanager.mgrid and rownum = 1
group by graduate.univid
order by count(graduate.univid) desc;
```

but when put as subquery, ORACLE sqlplus keep giving "missing right parenthesis" error

```
select university.univname
from university
where exists 
(
select graduate.univid
from graduate, projectmanager, university
where graduate.empid = projectmanager.mgrid and rownum = 1
group by graduate.univid
order by count(graduate.univid)
);
```

I have checked similar questions on stackoverflow, but doesn't really help

Comment: Your query looks incorrect for a variety of reasons.  It is missing a join condition (and you should always use explicit `JOIN`).  And you are aggregating when you are fetching only one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use exists so you have to give the condition of university and the subquery. you missed it you get the error i ll guess the right query:

```
select t1.univname
from university t1
where exists 
(  select 1 from (
   select graduate.univid
   from graduate, projectmanager, university
   where graduate.empid = projectmanager.mgrid and rownum = 1
   group by graduate.univid
   order by count(graduate.univid)) t2 where t2.univid = t1.univid
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that rest of your logic is correct, the problem is `order by` clause. You should **not** use it in subquery.
Try this

```
select university.univname
from university
where exists 
(
select graduate.univid
from graduate, projectmanager, university
where graduate.empid = projectmanager.mgrid and rownum = 1
group by graduate.univid
);
```

You can try it out yourself.

This query will return `1`

```
select 1 from dual
where exists
(select 2 as id from dual)
```

But this will fail and give you `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

```
select 1 from dual
where exists
(select 2 as id from dual order by id )
```

Comment: in hindsight "missing right parenthesis" is understandable because Oracle expected it after the "from dual" part, but nevertheless a nice catch!